# Connecting to database and CRUD

Tags: php, pdo

I'm working on a website application lately, which is basically a client/project management. 
Since the start I knew about the necessity to separate the logic, view and data functionality to make a cleaner code that can be mantained, so I had in mind a 3-layer approach. Problem and doubts starts when I put the theory in practice and start writing code.

So let's start with Clients for example.

http://pastebin.com/47SKYwuX

Thats how my Clients.class.php looks like. That doesn't look good in my eyes, because the database queries should not be there, it's not a Client responsability (is it?), but then, where do I place the CRUD operations for Clients and other, I was thinking of making a DAO for every class object that needs to operate with my DB, maybe a general DAO abstract class wich connects to the database and the other ones would be childs, would that be correct?

Talking about the connection to database, thats how the dbbconnect is implemented, this is included by all those other classes.

```
$user= '';
$pass= '';
$bdname= '';

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing', $user, $pass);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit('Database error.');
}
```

I'm sure this is not how PDO should be used, since I'm globally using this `$pdo` on the other classes. How should I be using it properly?

And finally, I've got doubts when it comes to fetching data from database. When it comes to fetching one row from database, which would be one Client, I would map this to an Object and return it as a Client (not an array of values). Should I return an array of Objects when I'm fetching All Clients?

I hope someone can put some light in those doubts and thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use a framework which meets your requirement ?

Comment: try use mvc-framework, yii for example

Comment: I've considered that aswell, and in fact I'm on my way learning how the MVC pattern works on the web, since it's slightly different from what I've seen before. But I don't want to really jump into a framework without knowing how it works first.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to look into. And frankly theres more than one question in your "question".

About modeling your classes you might look into something called Data Driven Design. Thats exactly about what your talking about with splitting the Model and the saving to database into separate components. Google around a little and read up on some examples.

You might also want to look into something called an ORM. Basically its an abstraction so that you don't have to write explicit database queries. Instead you write how to map Objects to database Tables.

Regarding your question about having PDO instances in global scope: You want to use something called Dependecy Injection. Look into [Fabien Potencier](http://fabien.potencier.org/) (the author of the framework Symfony). On his blog he writes a few good posts on why and how to use Dependency Injection.

**Edit**

After some friendly suggestions from @FinalForm I'll try to make an example on how you could do it:

```
<?php

class Client {
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $email;

    public function __construct($id, $name, $email) {
        $this->setId($id);
        $this->setName($name);
        $this->setEmail($email);
    }

    public function setId($id) { $this->id = $id; }
    public function getId() { return $this->id; }
    public function setName($name) { $this->name = $name; }
    public function getName() { return $this->name; }
    public function setEmail($email) { $this->email = $email; }
    public function getEmail() { return $this->email; }
}

class ClientFactory {
    public function createClient($name, $email) {
        return new Client(
            $this->newID(),
            $name,
            $email
        );
    }

    private function newID() {
        // return a new id
    }
}

class ClientDao {
    private $dbh;

    public function __construct(PDO $databaseHandler) {
        $this->dbh = $databaseHandler;
    }

    // Create-method
    public function persist(Client client) {
        $query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO clients (id, name, email) VALUES (:id, :name, :email)");
        $query->execute(array(
            'id' => client->getId(),
            'name' => client->getName(),
            'email' => client->getEmail()
        ));
    }

    // Create simelar methods for the rest of the CRUD-methods
}

// Usage

require 'config.php';

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing', $user, $pass);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit('Database error.');
}

$clientFactory = new ClientFactory();
$clientDao = new ClientDao($pdo);

$client1 = $clientFactory->createClient("Bob", "bob@gmail.com");
$client2 = $clientFactory->createClient("Dick", "dick@gmail.com");
$client3 = $clientFactory->createClient("Roger", "roger@gmail.com");

$clientDao->persist($client1);
$clientDao->persist($client2);
$clientDao->persist($client3);
```

I hope that might explain how you might do it. The idea is to separate the creation of the object and the saving to the database.

Comment: He's asking for how to design it from the ground up. He's not asking for "what to use". Your answer is irrelevant and does not answer his question. It is *not* constructive.

Comment: Yes it does. He is asking architectural questions on how best to code. I pointed him in the right direction on which principles to study for best writing code.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You just told to him RTFM. You provided no insight into his question. It is practically saying, "Go use Google". You provided sources and that's it. No "direct" answers. This is an answer site.

Comment: If you "explain" to him data driven design, then that is answering the question.

Comment: In first place thanks for your answer and the information you've given, my troubles are more related on how to approach those patterns theory on the paper. I'm aware that there are multiple correct ways, but I'm just trying to 'fix' the one I started. So focusing more on a single aswer: If I made a DAO which would have all the CRUD operations from my entity classe such as client project etc, how could I efficiently connect it to the database using PDO? General DAO which connects to the DB and the childs get it by heritage?

Answer (score -1):

K, assuming it's a straight forward client management system...

So there may be a "clients" table. Each row within the table should be thought of as an object. So you'd have class Client. When that class is instantiated, it could represent 1 row within the table. Data from that 1 row would be mapped to that object. And maybe you could subclass Client to multiple Clients. So you would do class Client extends Clients {...}. The "Clients" class could be used to represent multiple rows within the table.

So there would be:

> class Client extends Clients {...}
>
> class Clients extends Database { public function insert() {...} }

And class Database (see above) would do the database operations you're wanting.

So whenever you need to do insertion, you could do something like that..

> $client = new Client();
>
> $client->setName("McDonalds");
>
> $client->setRevenue("$2 billion");
>
> $client->insert( $client );

This way, all model level classes like clients could be created and sub-classed off of an underlying database class where they can all share it's deep level database usage.

Comment: Please show me where it's bad practice? Where did you see or read this? Can you provide an additional proof?

Comment: He's asking for how to design it from the ground up. He's not asking for "what to use". Your answer is irrelevant and does not answer his question. It is not constructive. Please "read" the user's questions and answer it. That's the point of this site. It is tantamount to saying RTFM.

Comment: Also, you have not supported your statement "extending a Database class is a really bad practice". WHERE DID YOU SEE THIS???

Comment: You don't want to extend a database class in every class working with the database. Instead you should pass around an instance of PDO or some other kind of database abstraction to the classes which needs to talk with the database. Preferably you should pass it around using Dependency Injection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73201/discussion-between-knarf-and-finalform).

Comment: Thanks both of you for your answers, but keep it calm! I don't really like this approach, because as Knarf mentioned, this would break the Single Responsability principle which I'm trying to accomplish. But it's very interesting to see other aproaches on the same goal, and I'll look further into it. Thanks

Comment: You're thinking too much bro - just do it. I would have finished this like 4 hours ago. And if I needed to make corrections, then it's quick to make corrections.